# Textbooks/papers to learn about the physics of the CMB

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, cosmic-microwave-background

I am a PhD student working on observational cosmology. My research is based on the experimental side of it (receiver design, etc.) but I would like to get deep into the CMB and CMB statistics. I have found several resources and have read some of the papers but I feel like they are a bit "unconnected".

Does anyone know where I could start? I thought of just studying Ruth Durrer's (The Cosmic Microwave Background) book, but I am not sure if it will be complete enough.

Comment: If you're that close to it, surely your advisor or peers are good sources of recommendations.

Comment: Since I don't know exactly what you want to read, try the [arXiv search query](https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-term=CMB&terms-0-field=title&classification-physics=y&classification-physics_archives=astro-ph&classification-include_cross_list=include&date-filter_by=all_dates&date-year=&date-from_date=&date-to_date=&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=50&order=-announced_date_first). Also, see the original WMAP  and Planck data https://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/planck/publications. LAMBDA might also be helpful: https://lambda.gsfc.nasa.gov/.